# Is this the proper way of denying remote connections to jssh on Linux?

Tags: ruby, security, watir, firewatir, jssh

I don't know if jssh has any security built-in. While testing web apps, I would only like to be able to connect to jssh from localhost. I added the following lines to iptables :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --dport 9997 -j LOG
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --dport 9997 -j DROP
```

will they provide the security I need?

EDIT : this is related to programming. The test is written in ruby . But for the test to work, jssh must be enabled. By default, jssh runs on port 9997 and accepts all incoming connections. Once connected, it accepts commands from the connected user. Imagine the potential harm it could do if someone connects to a jssh shell that's being ran by an user with administrative priviledges .

EDIT2 : Just because I don't have a problem with the code I write, this doesn't mean that this question should be dismissed. I think it's a legitimate question. I would like to know if I have some control over one of the tools I'm using.

Comment: Could you add some details to explain how this is a programming question? Right now it sounds like an OS/App configuration question.

Comment: So you don't have any problem with the actual programming involved?

Comment: If you don't intend of providing *useful* information, please navigate away from this page.

Comment: Just leading you to an understanding that because this is a problem that a programmer has, it is not automatically programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tested if the default configuration allows connections from outside localhost?

AFAIK, by default it binds to 127.0.0.1 (only localhost), and not to 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

SSH only accepts connections from authenticated users. It is about *nothing but* security. Your question remains unclear.